# QML - TextArea and TextEdit, which one is better?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

There are 2 QML types of the text edit. They're [TextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-textedit.html) and [TextArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-textarea.html). I wonder which one is better? What should I use?

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear. Better for what? What are your requirements for the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-textarea.html#details) for `TextArea` should be enough to work this out:

> `TextArea` is a multi-line text editor. `TextArea` extends `TextEdit` with a placeholder text functionality, and adds decoration.

Hence, if "has more functionality" is your definition of "better", that would be `TextArea`.

Of course, it all depends on whether the added functionality is necessary since added functionality is rarely without *some* cost. As to which one *you* should use, that really depends on your own needs, so it's hard to make a definitive answer to that part of your question.

You should investigate whether the added functionality is needed in your case.

Answer (score -4):

textedit is best for me
you can use text area for some place